# How to Change ClientID in Google Analytics iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a query regarding `Google Analytics` clientID. I know that GA assign a `UUID` for each users internally. Can we set custom `UUID` from device as below

```
[tracker set:kGAIClientId value:[UUID getUUID]];  //Getting UUID if the device & setting against client id.
 [tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createScreenView] build]];
```

So my question is that, can we set custom `kGAIClientId` in Google Analytics.

Any idea or suggestion would be very great.

Thanks,